# AutoLayout doesn't work for custom UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, uikit

I am trying to create a custom UIView and use auto layout with it. The auto layout relative to its parent view is working correctly, but its internal elements aren't being positioned or sized correctly.

How it's looking right now:

[image]

How it should look:

[image: Correct design]

This is the code for the custom view:

```
import UIKit

class PopularDrinkView: UIView {
    lazy var drinkImageView: UIImageView = {
        let div = UIImageView(image: HomePageImages.profileIconImage)
        div.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        div.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        
        div.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return div
    }()
    
    lazy var drinkNameLabel: UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.text = "aeeijk"
        label.textColor = .black
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var drinkSubtitleLabel: UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.textColor = .gray
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addDrinkImageLayout()
        addTitleLayout()
        addSubtitleLayout()
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    func addContentToView(drink: DrinkModel) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: drink.strDrinkThumb!)!)
                let image = UIImage(data: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.drinkImageView.image = image
                    self.drinkNameLabel.text = drink.strDrink
                    self.drinkSubtitleLabel.text = drink.strCategory
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addDrinkImageLayout() {
        addSubview(drinkImageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            drinkImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            drinkImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            drinkImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    func addTitleLayout() {
        addSubview(drinkNameLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            drinkNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: drinkImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            drinkNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
            drinkNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func addSubtitleLayout() {
        addSubview(drinkSubtitleLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            drinkSubtitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: drinkImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            drinkSubtitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: drinkNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            drinkSubtitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping out!

**EDITED:** on the 2nd image, on the bottom it can be seen that the image is on the left, and the text is on the right. That's the layout I tried to apply, but on mine the image grew a lot and the text isn't being shown.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which parts of the first image needs to be transformed into which parts of the second one?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind done, added an edit explaining